# Hide "Add a debit or credit card" option in paypal checkout menu

Tags: python-3.x, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, subscription

Hi I am trying to implement a paypal subscription, but I dont want the **"Add a debit or credit card"** option in it as shown below

[image]

is there any way to hide it.

Comment: What could be a possible good reason to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove these from your account.

step 1 Click Wallet at the top of the page.
step 2 Click the card you want to remove.
step 3 Click Remove card.

[reference](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/How-do-I-remove-a-credit-card-or-debit-card-from-my-PayPal-account-FAQ1862)